# BizTalk Custom Adapter EventLog Spam when Disabled

Tags: c#, adapter, biztalk, webdav

I created a WebDAV Send/Receive Adapter for BizTalk and everything is working fine, but when I disable the Receive Location the Eventlog gets flooded with 3 Errors.

1. The adapter "WebDAV" raised an error message. Details "The given key was not present in the dictionary.".
2. The receive location "RL.WebDAV.HBS" with URL "WebDAV://URI//kstore/C20709T11/tmp/Temp" is shutting down. Details:"The Messaging Engine failed while notifying an adapter of its configuration. ".
3. The Messaging Engine failed to remove the receive location "RL.WebDAV.HBS" with URL "WebDAV://URI//kstore/C20709T11/tmp/Temp" from the adapter "WebDAV". Reason: "The given key was not present in the dictionary.".

I'm not Using a single Dictionary in my Code, what dictionary could be meant?

It doesn't stop till I stop and restart the Host Instance.

There is a Terminate Method in my ReceiverAdapter that I could override, but there is nothing where is see the need to destroy.

Dispose in my ReceiverEndpoint:

```
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("BizTalk Server", "[WebDAV Adapter] Stopped Adapter UniqueCode: 635265412", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        base.Dispose();
        this.isStopped = true;
        this.timer.Dispose();
        this.transportProxy = null;
        this.connection.IsStopped = true;
        this.connection.AbortSession();
        this.connection.CloseSession();

        if (Marshal.IsComObject(connection))  
        {
            while (0 <Marshal.ReleaseComObject(connection))
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(connection);
            }
        }

        GC.SuppressFinalize(connection);
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged through your dispose code to make sure none of those calls are raising any of those exceptions?  FWIW, I believe I've seen this with another custom adapter (schedule task), and was never sure why.